# build an Sql query in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need to pass a sql query to c#.

Here is the query:

```
select 
    T010.A010_nom_ent A010_nom_ent
from
    T010_ENTIDADE T010,
    T016_USUARIO T016
        left outer join
    T307_CELULA_USUARIO T307 ON T307.A306_seq_celula = 0
        and T307.A016_cod_usuario = T016.A016_cod_usuario
where
    T010.A010_cod_entidade = T016.A016_cod_usuario
order by 1
```

and the code is here:

```
public List<Entidade> ListarUsuariosCelula()
    {
        List<Entidade> lstEntidades = null;

        try
        {
            oInvitroEntities = new InvitroEntities();

            lstEntidades = (***here is where i want to put the query***)


            return lstEntidades;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogErro.Trace(ex);
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            oInvitroEntities = null;
        }
    }
```

Here is one exemple of what i want to do (i will put just a piece of the code):

```
try
        {
            oInvitroEntities = new InvitroEntities();

            lstCelula = (from cel in oInvitroEntities.T306_CELULA
                               select new Celula { Codigo = cel.A306_seq_celula, Descricao = cel.A306_dsc_celula }).ToList();


            return lstCelula;
        }
```

Comment: What is your ORM? Is it EntityFramework or something else? Could you show us your mapping? And your query seems not working.

Comment: It is working, and i just need to pass that to c#. The other things i have to do i know how

Comment: Usually queries are passed to SQL Server not the other way.... what do you mean _pass a sql query to c#._

Comment: Do you mean you need to translate the query to C# (I'm assuming Entity Framework, specifically)?

Comment: I will edit my question and put there an exemple of what a need

Comment: If you didn't use a mapping, just want to run a query, check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090(v=vs.110).aspx#_SqlClient

Comment: this part of query can be safely removed: 'left outer join    T307_CELULA_USUARIO T307 ON T307.A306_seq_celula = 0 and T307.A016_cod_usuario = T016.A016_cod_usuario' cause you did not use its result

Comment: The mapping (data model) is the InvitroEntities()

Answer (score 2):

You can use a multi-line string for ease of reading. Assuming you have already setup the database connection and command object, you would need to do something like this for storing your query:

```
    string query = @"select 
    T010.A010_nom_ent as A010_nom_ent
from
    T010_ENTIDADE T010,
    T016_USUARIO T016
        left outer join
    T307_CELULA_USUARIO T307 ON T307.A306_seq_celula = 0
        T307.A016_cod_usuario = T016.A016_cod_usuario
where
    T010.A010_cod_entidade = T016.A016_cod_usuario
order by 1";
```

Note, I've corrected your query:

```
select 
    T010.A010_nom_ent as A010_nom_ent
from
    T010_ENTIDADE T010,
    T016_USUARIO T016
        left outer join
    T307_CELULA_USUARIO T307 ON T307.A306_seq_celula = 0
        T307.A016_cod_usuario = T016.A016_cod_usuario
where
    T010.A010_cod_entidade = T016.A016_cod_usuario
order by 1
```

If you want to rename a column, you use the `as` keyword to do so. Aliases are only for referring to tables.

Comment: If you are really going for ease of reading, a multi-line string prefixed with `@` would probably be better, with the added bonus of not instantiating an object for nothing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I edited my answer to use a multi-line string.

Comment: There is a rule in my team for the system to use only like i posted in my question

Comment: @user3107374, this answer was added for trolling.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that part with left outer join can be removed (it will not change result of query).
So you sql query can be reqrite in linq to entities (there is single inner join cause i droped off your left outer join):

```
oInvitroEntities.T010_ENTIDADE.Join(oInvitroEntities.T016_USUARIO,
                                    t10=>t10.A010_cod_entidade, 
                                    t16=>t16.A016_cod_usuario, 
                                    (t10, t16) => t10.A010_nom_ent);
```